# Vuejs 2 trying to call api multiple times untill all the data is retreiced

Tags: ajax, api, vue.js, rest, sharepoint

I'm trying to use Vuejs 2 to call an endpoint API multiple times until all data is retrieved.

I'm using the SharePoint REST api and the results come back in an object `res.d.results`, however I can only query 5000 items at a time.

If `rest.d.__next` exists, it also has the endpoint to the next batch of data.

When I run this code I can see in the chrome debugger that the second call is made but the data is never pushed to the table and I get this message in the browser console

> Event.path is deprecated and will be removed. Please use Event.composedPath() instead.

```
new Vue ({
    el:"#app",
    data: {
    test: "this is my test",
    pg:[]

    },
    created: function(){
        console.log("working");
        this.loopData("https://srvsharepoint1p/sites/tactical_squad/ArhivaTool/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Dosare')/items?$top=1000", this);

    },

    methods: {
        getListData: function(url,that){ // function that calls the api 
          console.log("getting data");
            var headers={
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
         return $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type: "GET",
                headers: headers,
                success: function(data){
                    lData = data;
                }
            });

        },

        loopData: function (web){ // function to loop through API calls until all data is retrieved. 
            this.getListData(web).then(res => {

                    console.log(res);
                    this.pg.push(...res.d.results)
                  if (res.d.__next) { // if there is a next page do another api call 
                    this.getListData(res.d.__next); // try to call the api again
                  } else {
                    console.log('aborted')
                  }
            })
        }
    }})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out

It seems I was doing recursion wrong. Hope this helps someone else it's using axios now to get data instead of ajax

```
new Vue ({
    el:"#app",
    data: {
    test: "this is my test",
    pg:[], // table data
   counter:0
        
    },
    created: function(){
        console.log("working");
        this.getListData("https://srvsharepoint1p/sites/tactical_squad/ArhivaTool/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Dosare')/items?$top=5000"  ); //endpoint

    },
    
    methods: {
        getListData: function(url){ //recursive function that calls itself untill all data is retreived
            var vm = this
          console.log("getting data");
          axios.get(url).then(function(res){
            if (res.data["odata.nextLink"] ) { // check if another page needs to be requested
                vm.pg.push(...res.data.value); // push values into table object
                vm.getListData(res.data["odata.nextLink"]); //call function again 
              } 
            else {
                console.log('aborted');
                alert("Tabelul este incarcat, se poata folosi butonul de exprot")
              }
           
          })
          .catch(function(error){
              alert(error);
          })
        }})
```